# difference between url in browser and value of server_name in nginx configuration

Tags: linux, nginx

What's the difference between url in browser and value of server_name? And if a well-known hostname is specified in server_name,what would happen?
In nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.org www.example.org; // if google.com is specified, what happens?
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a virtual host which means, on same nginx/IP you can host multiple websites.

So adding a `server_name` helps nginx to separate traffic from one website to other. So if you have two blocks

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example1.org www.example2.org;
}
```

Now `example.org`, `www.example.org` would be handled by first block and request to `example1.org`, `www.example2.org` will be handled by second block. There are other options like using mask `*.example.com` or using patterns `~^ww[\d]\.example\.com`.

You can get more details on below link

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: Yeah,I've read the doc and then ask the question. DNS is used to host name and IP address. Is the "www.example.org" in server_name equal to url in the browser? Maybe the key word is "virtual host".

Comment: Yes, if you browse `http://www.example.org/` the server_name is `www.example.org`

Comment: If "www.google.com" is value of sever_name, does it mean traffic will go through this machine when user input this url in browser? Certainly not, what am I missing?

Comment: It will only go to your server if the DNS resolution for `www.google.com` resolve to your Server's IP. This cannot happen if you go through normal DNS server. But you can create your own DNS server and use that in your machine or you can make a host entry for `www.google.com` in your machine with your server's IP. This would make your browser go to your server for `www.google.com`. But ONLY for your machine where these changes were made.

Comment: I don't know whether my understanding is right: in common usage, one IP can host multiple hostname. Then all the traffic of these hostnames comes into the same machine and match url in browser with specific sever_name block in nginx.conf. Is this right?

Comment: That is: domainName1. domainName2, and domainName3 ->IPAddr. Then all the traffic of domainName1, domainName2 and domainName3 comes into the same machine. When user visits domainName1 in browser, only server whose server_name matches "hostName1" in nginx.conf will be chosen. Is this right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153256/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-user7328234).